# Passing variables to functions in Python

Tags: python, selenium, nose

Im writing test scripts in Python for Selenium web testing.

How do I pass parameters through a Python function to call in a later function?
I first have a login test function.
Then I have a new user registration function. Im trying to pass the Username and Password I use in the registration function to the `testLogin()` function that I call inside the `testRegister()` function.

This is my python code:

```
userName = "admin"
password = "admin"

#pass username and password variables to this function
def testLogin(userName,password):
  browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  browser.get("http://url/login")

  element = browser.find_element_by_name("userName")
  element.send_keys(userName)

  element = browser.find_element_by_name("userPassword")
  element.send_keys(password)

  element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

  browser.close()

# test registration
def testRegister():
  browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  browser.get("http://url/register")

  #new username variable
  newUserName = "test"
  element = browser.find_element_by_name("regUser")
  element.send_keys(newUserName)

  #new password variable
  newUserPassword = "test"
  element = browser.find_element_by_name("regPassword")
  element.send_keys(newUserPassword)

  #
  #now test if user is registered, I want to call testLogin with the test user name and pw.
  testLogin(newUserName,newUserPassword)

  browser.close()
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or a different result than you expected? You can pass variables defined in a function to a different function without doing anything special.

Comment: From what I see the testuser has not been created since testregister is not called. You will have to do testregister() then testlogin("test", "test")

Answer (score 0):

Any values you have around—whether you got them as function arguments, or received them by calling functions, or just defined them on the fly—you can pass as arguments to any other function.

So, if you want to pass some values through `testRegister` for it to use with `testLogin`, just do this:

```
# test registration
def testRegister(userName, password):
  browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  browser.get("http://url/register")

  element = browser.find_element_by_name("regUser")
  element.send_keys(userName)

  element = browser.find_element_by_name("regPassword")
  element.send_keys(password)
```

Is there something more you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new function to run all of your tests.

```
def run_tests(username, password):
    testLogin(username,password)
    testRegister(username, password)
```

You will need to modify testRegister so it accepts username and password parameters.

Then you can start your script with run_tests('admin', 'letmein')